# Want to convert date from a specific format

Tags: r, date, date-formatting

I have a list of data that has date information in the format:
11-Feb-08, 13-Feb-08, 2-Mar-08 etc. How can I change all the entries in this column to be in dd/mm/yy format. I have tried as.Date and as.POSIXct but it converts it to NAs. sos pls help.

Comment: try `as.POSIXct('11-Feb-08', format = '%d-%b-%y')`. You can do `?strptime` to see the meaning of each format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below Code using lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
c<-data.frame("Date" = c("11-Feb-08","13-Feb-08", "2-Mar-08"))
c$Date<-dmy(c$Date, tz = "Asia/Kolkata")
str(c$Date)
```

You will get below result:

```
POSIXct[1:3], format: "2008-02-11" "2008-02-13" "2008-03-02"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NAs for the date values because of the formatting issue. Provide appropriate date format in  `format` argument of `as.POSIXct` or `as.Date` function.

As per the date example(11-Feb-08), the appropriate format would be :
`format = '%d-%b-%y'`.

Do look at the documentation using  `?strptime` for format related query.It is well documented for each kind of date format.

Comment: @Gregor, I have faced similar issues before based on date format and this is the solution that worked for me. Do `?strptime` to see the all date format.

Comment: @Gregor, I have updated the answer as per suggestion, Thanks for the suggestion. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Gregor , Even im kind of new here, Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Much improved! Thanks for being open to feedback. Hope you keep coming back :)

Comment: All Thanks to you @Gregor for the valuable suggestions!